# How to set <ul> verticaly?

Tags: html, css

I currently have this  on my footer that I want to put it on vertical in smaller screens but don't know exactly how to do that. Not sure if it matters but I'm using the flexbox model on the website.

```css
body { background-color: black; }

.menu-footer {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.menu-footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-footer li {
  margin-left: 45px;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.menu-footer a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.social-media ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-media li {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 40px 0 10px 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="menu-footer">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="transition" href="./index.html">home</a></li>
      <li><a class="transition" href="./about.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a class="transition" href="./work.html">work</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="transition" href="./contact.html">contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

How it looks right now

[image]

Comment: Just remove `display: flex` from `.menu-footer ul`.

Answer (score 0):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

```
.social-media ul { flex-direction: column; }
```

Answer (score 0):

to achieve the vertical style in smaller screens just add the `display: block` in `.menu-footer ul` style in the media query specifying the desired screen size.

```css
body{
  background: black;
}

.menu-footer {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.menu-footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
.menu-footer li {
  margin-left: 45px;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.menu-footer a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.social-media ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-media li {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 40px 0 10px 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .menu-footer ul{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="menu-footer">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="transition" href="./index.html">home</a></li>
      <li><a class="transition" href="./about.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a class="transition" href="./work.html">work</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="transition" href="./contact.html">contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: now check the above code. It might solve your issue... :)

Answer (score 0):

try it

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .toolbar ul {
            display:table-row;
        }
        .toolbar ul li
        {
            display: table-cell;
            height: 100px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 10px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .toolbar ul li a {
            display:table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            height:100px;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
        .toolbar ul li.button a {
            height:50px;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">first item<br />
                first item<br />
                first item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">last item</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="#">button<br />
                button</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
share
```

Comment: You are showing XHTML but the question is tagged and uses HTML.